# Setting Input value in jquery variable

Tags: jquery

How would you change or set the value of an input in a jquery variable object.
For example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
htmlString = '<div><input name="hello" value="AAAAAAAA" /> </div>';
$htmlString = $(htmlString);
$htmlString.find('[name="hello"]').val('world')
console.log( $htmlString.find('[name="hello"]').val() );
console.log( $htmlString.prop('outerHTML') );
</script>
```

The value of [name="hello"] shows to be 'world' in the first console.log, but in the second it shows that it is still 'AAAAAAAA'.
I am needing it to stay as 'world'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.attr()` to set new attribute value, witch call `.setAttribute()` in pure js and both of them make changes in DOM structure.

> Why first console displays "world" as well ?

e.g. if you set value of input like

```
inputID.value = "world";
//value changed but if you try to view HTML source you see no changes
inputID.setAttribute("value","world");
//here your source code changed
```

Also in jQuery

```
inputID.val("world");
//value changed but if you try to view source HTML you see no changes
inputID.attr("value","world");
//here your source code changed
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
htmlString = '<div><input name="hello" value="AAAAAAAA" /> </div>';
$htmlString = $(htmlString);
$htmlString.find('[name="hello"]').attr("value",'world');
console.log( $htmlString.find('[name="hello"]').val() );
console.log( $htmlString.prop('outerHTML') );
</script>
```

Comment: While that code does work, the other should work as well, right? I mean it is obviously being set, otherwise the first console log wouldn't show 'world'.

Comment: What's the other ? first console displays `world` because `.attr()` updated the attribute value.

Comment: Sorry, I meant my OG code. The OG first console displays world as well.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Completely forgot input wasn't part of the DOM.